# Ctrl+alt and shift+alt change language

Tags: windows

In Windows you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> if you want to change language. But, is it possible to have each of this combination for manipulating? I mean, is it possible to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in one time without changing every time in settings?

I want to have an option what to press, either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>,- now I could set just one of this settings.

Comment: you can disable the key mappings.

Comment: You seem to have things backwards.. unless windows has changed.   http://i49.tinypic.com/35hn603.jpg    windows xp has ctrl+shift,  OR.    alt+shift.     There are no other options.   You seem to want to change it to what- as that screenshot shows - it has. To put it another way, windows allows ((CTRL OR ALT) AND SHIFT).  or to put it another way.   ((CTRL AND SHIFT) OR (ALT AND SHIFT))